# Photo uploaded to firebase does not open correctly

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

In storage it creates a hierarchy of folders, the same is in the path of the image, inside these folders it creates the image file, but when I download this image it does not open.

```
  const finalizarAlbum = () => {
    let albumNumber = Date.now();
    let username = email.split('@')[0] + '_' + albumNumber;

    let pathImage =
      'file:///data/user/0/com.master/cache/tm-rn-image-crop-picker/8f403c24-c538-43f4-bb8d-e6c83be46a36.jpg';

    firebase
      .storage()
      .ref()
      .child('imagens')
      .putString(pathImage)
      .on(
        'state_changed',
        snapshot => {
          let pct = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        },

        error => {
          alert(error.code);
        },
        () => {}
      );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your code calls `putString()` it is writing the string `"file:///data/user/0/com.master/cache/tm-rn-image-crop-picker/8f403c24-c538-43f4-bb8d-e6c83be46a36.jpg"` to Cloud Storage, not the contents of the file that the string refers to.

To upload the actual contents of the file, you'll want to call the [`putFile()` method](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/storage/reference/Reference#putFile) (if you're using [`react-native-firebase`](https://rnfirebase.io/), or the [`put` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files?hl=en#upload_from_a_blob_or_file) with a `File` or `Blob` reference (if you're using the regular JavaScript SDK.

Comment: putfile is not a function. I am importing "import firebase from 'firebase'; is this the problem?

Comment: Ah, you're not using [`react-native-firebase`](https://rnfirebase.io/) then? I'd definitely have a look at that package, as this method is just one of the handy utilities it has. If you're using the regular JavaScript SDK for Cloud Storage from Firebase, the method is called put. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files?hl=en#upload_from_a_blob_or_file for docs and an example. I also expanded my answer to include both scenarios.